# How to open hibernated windows NTFS partition?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10, ntfs, partitioning

I have a dual-boot PC with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I keep my Windows on fastboot mode and hence the NTFS partitions used in Windows, not open in Ubuntu. I want them to open in Ubuntu while keeping Windows in hibernation (fastboot mode).

I already searched and googled but I can't get an acceptable solution. How can I do so?

Comment: You can't. Windows' hibernation format is secret. You have to shut Windows down the right way, no hibernation, no fast boot, ... if you want to see NTFS in Linux.

Comment: Even if it were possible, it's dangerous; windows makes the assumption (with hibernation) that no changes were made, so if you make any during a hibernated state, it'll create fs (filesystem) errors and you're risking data-loss (hence restrictions)..

Comment: You can open it read-only, or not at all.

Comment: accessing hibernated partitions can quickly cause file and partition corruption. Disable fast startup and hibernation if you want to access them from ubuntu.

Comment: I won't disable fastboot in Windows (as it'll start dead slow then) but just if I can access it in Read only mode, I'm okay with that. Please tell me how can I open it as Read only?

Comment: You can't reliably open it read-only, since hibernated systems can contain partially-completed filesystem operations.